# C# IEnumerator is unchangable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a trouble with code below. What it does it builds a single line of road, one element after another.

```
currentLength = Random.Range(maxFloorLength - 2, maxFloorLength);
    List<GameObject> tempList = new List<GameObject>();

    for (int i = 0; i < currentLength; ++i)
    {
        foreach (GameObject g in pooledFloor)
        {
            if (!g.activeInHierarchy)
            {
                g.SetActive(true);
                g.transform.position = startPoint + buildDirection * i;
                g.transform.DOScaleY(5, 0.25f).Play();
                lastFloorPositions.Add(g.transform.position);
                tempList.Add(g);
                break;
            }
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
    }
```

While this works as expected, when i change this to:

```
    currentLength = Random.Range(maxFloorLength - 2, maxFloorLength);
    List<GameObject> tempList = new List<GameObject>();

    for (int i = 0; i < currentLength; ++i)
    {
        foreach (GameObject g in pooledFloor)
        {
            if (!g.activeInHierarchy)
            {
                g.transform.position = startPoint + buildDirection * i;
                lastFloorPositions.Add(g.transform.position);
                tempList.Add(g);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    foreach (GameObject g in tempList)
    {
        g.SetActive(true);
        g.transform.DOScaleY(5, 0.25f).Play();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
    }
```

all it does is create ONE part of road (the one that should be at the end of tempList list). What i want is that script adds all the prefabs to list BEFORE doing something else with them, so i can add few thing in between. I tried to change it to void function, and calling some of this code as ienumerator, changing loop types etc. but nothing seems to work and i have no clue why is it not working. I checked with Debug.Log whether it still finds more than 1 prefab, and it does, but it only activates and scales ONE of them. I bet it's something obvious, but i just can't see it :/

How it looks:

[image: How its working]

How it should be looking:

[image: How it should look]

Forgot to mention - its all inside of IEnumerator

Comment: not sure, but maybe you could/should ask this in http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: The first pass is nested and the second pass is not. Try:

Comment: @Kuniq check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first code when you call `g.SetActive(true);`, in next iteration of `for` loop the `if` condition for the same object wont be true so it will evaluate for next inactive object and add it to `tempList`.

In second case for all iteration of `for loop` it keeps evaluating for same object g (the first inactive object on `pooledFloor`) because it is not being activated.

To achieve your expected behaviour, I would suggest you to use `for-loop` instead of `for-each` on `pooledFloor` and remove the object from the list if its inactive.

something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < currentLength; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < pooledFloor.Count; j++) 
    {
        GameObject g = pooledFloor[j];
        if (!g.activeInHierarchy)
        {
            g.transform.position = startPoint + buildDirection * i;
            lastFloorPositions.Add(g.transform.position);
            tempList.Add(g);
            pooledFloor.Remove(g);  // Removing it from list would solve the problem.
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Removing from the list is sure good performance -wise (i guess) but the main issue was what you mentioned - i did not turn the game object on and then in future iterations it found that same object again and again, so what i did i just moved SetActive from bottom loop to upper, and then just enable Renderer component in the bottom loop. That pretty much solved everything ^^ thank you very much :) I just knew it was something as simple as that

Comment: I am pleased to be helpful. Please accept my answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

The first pass is nested and the second part is not. Try:

```
for (int i = 0; i<currentLength; ++i)
{
    foreach (GameObject g in tempList)
    {
        g.SetActive(true);
        g.transform.DOScaleY(5, 0.25f).Play();
    }
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of it like this:

```
public void passONE()
    {
        currentLength = Random.Range(maxFloorLength - 2, maxFloorLength);
        List<GameObject> tempList = new List<GameObject>();

        for (int i = 0; i < currentLength; ++i)
        {
            foreach (GameObject g in pooledFloor)
            {
                if (!g.activeInHierarchy)
                {
                    g.transform.position = startPoint + buildDirection * i;
                    lastFloorPositions.Add(g.transform.position);
                    tempList.Add(g);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        passTwo(currentLength, tempList);

    }
    private void passTwo(double currentLength,List<GameObject> tempList)
    {


        for (int i = 0; i < currentLength; ++i)
        {
            foreach (GameObject g in tempList)
            {
                g.SetActive(true);
                g.transform.DOScaleY(5, 0.25f).Play();

            }
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
        }


    }
```